# Text doesn't appear when I set 0dp for parent element

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone explain to me what I need to do to get the text displayed inside a LinearLayout with a height of 0dp (slightly white on image). I want to pull the LinearLayout down, so I use 0dp. But then the text is not displayed.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/imageGray">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loginHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loginFunctionallity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_screen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginHeader">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Would be easier to use a ConstraintLayout instead of a LinearLayout. It would prevent having this issue and you could put the text more precisely inside it

Comment: I tried your code and I am able to see the text perfectly, can you set some text color to your text view? maybe the theme color for text is set to white and verify from the design blueprint if the text view is visible at all.